# HTML5 Canvas Scallop Shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I really need help badly on how to create a scallop shape using Canvas
I tried playing around the cloud sample but it was really difficult for me to create what I've wanted.

I simply wanted to know the code for the scallop shape for rectangle and circle.

This is the image that What I've wanted. 
[image: Scallop Design]

It design doesn't have to exactly the same but as possible it does look like this.

THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCEEE..

Answer (score 2):

You can draw such a shape by using dotted line dash, like this(a bit tricky).

JavaScript:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 300;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const rect = [50, 50, 200, 200];
//draw dotted line dash.
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.setLineDash([0, 40]);
ctx.lineDashOffset = 20;
ctx.lineWidth = 42;
ctx.strokeStyle = "purple";
ctx.strokeRect(...rect);
//remove disuse range.
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.lineWidth = 38;
ctx.strokeRect(...rect);
ctx.fillRect(...rect);
```

Demo:
http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/iFR7

Comment: Why don't you just use quadratic curve?

Comment: In this case, my code does not need quadratic curve. But to use quadratic curve is more general, because my code is difficult to manipulate stroke width outline of shape.

Answer (score 2):

From an older answer but the question was very vague and has a lot of extra baggage. Here is a snippet from that answer. It has some extra code in it that may be helpful but not directly related.

The function display (about halfway down) does most of the work, adding the arcs to the object box.

See running demo for instruction

```js
const pointSize = 4;
const pointCol = "#4AF";
var arcDepth = -0.5; // depth of arc as a factor of line seg length
                       // Note to have arc go the other (positive) way you have
                       // to change the ctx.arc draw call by adding anticlockwise flag 
                       // see drawArc for more
                       
const arcCol = "#F92";
const arcWidth = 8;


// Find a circle that fits 3 points.
function fitCircleTo3P(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y, arc) {
    var vx,
    vy,
    c,
    c1,
    u;

    c = (p2x - p1x) / (p1y - p2y); // slope of vector from vec 1 to vec 2
    c1 = (p3x - p2x) / (p2y - p3y); // slope of vector from vec 2 to vec 3
    // This will not happen in this example
    if (c === c1) { // if slope is the same they must be on the same line
        return null; // points are in a line
    }
    // locate the center
    if (p1y === p2y) { // special case with p1 and p2 have same y
        vx = (p1x + p2x) / 2;
        vy = c1 * vx + (((p2y + p3y) / 2) - c1 * ((p2x + p3x) / 2));
    } else
        if (p2y === p3y) { // special case with p2 and p3 have same y
            vx = (p2x + p3x) / 2;
            vy = c * vx + (((p1y + p2y) / 2) - c * ((p1x + p2x) / 2));
        } else {
            vx = ((((p2y + p3y) / 2) - c1 * ((p2x + p3x) / 2)) - (u = ((p1y + p2y) / 2) - c * ((p1x + p2x) / 2))) / (c - c1);
            vy = c * vx + u;
        }
    arc.x = vx;
    arc.y = vy;
    vx = p1x - vx;
    vy = p1y - vy;
    arc.rad = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
    return arc;
}

var points = [];
var arcs = [];
function addArc(p1, p2, depth) {
    var arc = {
        p1 : p1,
        p2 : p2,
        depth : depth,
        rad : null, // radius
        a1 : null, // angle from
        a2 : null, // angle to
        x : null,
        y : null,
    }
    arcs.push(arc);
    return arc;
}
function calcArc(arc, depth) {
    var p = points[arc.p1]; // get points
    var pp = points[arc.p2];
    // change depth if needed
    depth = arc.depth = depth !== undefined ? depth : arc.depth;
    var vx = pp[0] - p[0]; // vector from p to pp
    var vy = pp[1] - p[1];
    var cx = (pp[0] + p[0]) / 2; // center point
    var cy = (pp[1] + p[1]) / 2; // center point
    var len = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy); // get length
    cx -= vy * depth; // find 3 point at 90 deg to line and dist depth
    cy += vx * depth;

    // To have depth as a fixed length uncomment 4 lines below and comment out 2 lines above.
    //var nx = vx / len;  // normalise vector
    //var ny = vy / len;
    //cx -= ny * depth; // find 3 point at 90 deg to line and dist depth
    //cy += nx * depth;


    fitCircleTo3P(p[0], p[1], cx, cy, pp[0], pp[1], arc); // get the circle that fits
    arc.a1 = Math.atan2(p[1] - arc.y, p[0] - arc.x); // get angle from circle center to first point
    arc.a2 = Math.atan2(pp[1] - arc.y, pp[0] - arc.x); // get angle from circle center to second point

}
function addPoint(x, y) {
    points.push([x, y]);
}
function drawPoint(x, y, size, col) {
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function drawArcStart(width,col){
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.beginPath();
    
}
function drawArc(arc){
    ctx.arc(arc.x,arc.y,arc.rad,arc.a1,arc.a2);
}    
function drawArcDone(){
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
function findClosestPoint(x, y, dist) {
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var p = points[i];
        var vx = x - p[0];
        var vy = y - p[1];
        var d = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
        if (d < dist) {
            dist = d;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

var dragging = false;
var drag = -1;
var dragX, dragY;
var recalcArcs = false;
var box;
//========================================================================
// New box code from here down

// creates the box when canvas is ready
var onResize = function(){
    box = {
        x : canvas.width * (1/8),
        y : canvas.height * (1/8),
        w : canvas.width * (6/8),
        h : canvas.height * (6/8),
        recalculate : true,
        arcCount : 20, // number of arcs to try and fit. Does not mean that it will happen
    }
}

function display() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

if(mouse.w !== 0){
    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 4){ // change arc depth
        if(mouse.w < 0){
            arcDepth *= 1/1.05;
        }else{
            arcDepth *= 1.05;
        }
        recalcArcs = true;
        
    }else{  // change arc count
        box.arcCount += Math.sign(mouse.w);
        box.arcCount = Math.max(4,box.arcCount);
        box.recalculate = true;
    }
    mouse.w = 0;
}
// drag out box;
if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
    if(!dragging){
        box.x = mouse.x;
        box.y = mouse.y;
        dragging = true;
    }
    box.w = mouse.x - box.x;
    box.h = mouse.y - box.y;
    box.recalculate = true;
    if(box.w <0){
        box.x = box.x + box.w;
        box.w = - box.w;
    }
    if(box.h <0){
        box.y = box.y + box.h;
        box.h = - box.h;
    }
}else{
    dragging = false;
}
// stop error
if(box.w === 0 || box.h === 0){
    box.recalculate = false;
}

// calculate box arcs
if(box.recalculate){
    // reset arrays
    points.length = 0;
    arcs.length = 0;
    // get perimeter length
    var perimLen = (box.w + box.h)* 2;
    // get estimated step size
    var step = perimLen / box.arcCount;
    // get inset size for width and hight
    var wInStep = (box.w - (Math.floor(box.w/step)-1)*step) / 2;
    var hInStep = (box.h - (Math.floor(box.h/step)-1)*step) / 2;
    // fix if box to narrow
    if(box.w < step){
        wInStep = 0;
        hInStep = 0;
        step = box.h / (Math.floor(box.h/step));
    }else if(box.h < step){
        wInStep = 0;
        hInStep = 0;
        step = box.w / (Math.floor(box.w/step));
        
    }
    
    // Add points clock wise
    var x = box.x + wInStep;
    while(x < box.x + box.w){ // across top
        addPoint(x,box.y);
        x += step;
    }
    var y = box.y + hInStep; 
    while(y < box.y + box.h){ // down right side
        addPoint(box.x + box.w,y);
        y += step;
    }
    x = box.x + box.w - wInStep;
    while(x > box.x){          // left along bottom
        addPoint(x,box.y + box.h);
        x -= step;
    }
    var y = box.y + box.h - hInStep;
    while(y > box.y){  // up along left side
        addPoint(box.x,y);
        y -= step;
    }
    // calculate arcs.
    for(var i =0; i <points.length; i++){
        calcArc(addArc(i,(i + 1) % points.length,arcDepth));
    }
    box.recalculate = false;
}
// recalculate arcs if needed
for(var i = 0; i < arcs.length; i ++){
    if(recalcArcs){
        calcArc(arcs[i],arcDepth);
    }
}
// draw arcs
drawArcStart(arcWidth,arcCol)
for(var i = 0; i < arcs.length; i ++){
    drawArc(arcs[i]);
}
drawArcDone();
recalcArcs = false;
}


//===========================================================================================
// END OF ANSWER

// Boiler plate code from here down. Does mouse,canvas,resize and what not
var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime = 0, firstRun = true; ;
(function () {
    const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
    var createCanvas,
    resizeCanvas,
    setGlobals,
    resizeCount = 0;
    createCanvas = function () {
        var c,
        cs;
        cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
        cs.position = "absolute";
        cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
        cs.zIndex = 1000;
        document.body.appendChild(c);
        return c;
    }
    resizeCanvas = function () {
        if (canvas === undefined) {
            canvas = createCanvas();
        }
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (typeof setGlobals === "function") {
            setGlobals();
        }
        if (typeof onResize === "function") {
            if (firstRun) {
                onResize();
                firstRun = false;
            } else {
                resizeCount += 1;
                setTimeout(debounceResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
    function debounceResize() {
        resizeCount -= 1;
        if (resizeCount <= 0) {
            onResize();
        }
    }
    setGlobals = function () {
        cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
    }
    mouse = (function () {
        function preventDefault(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        var mouse = {
            x : 0,
            y : 0,
            w : 0,
            alt : false,
            shift : false,
            ctrl : false,
            buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,
            bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3],
            active : false,
            bounds : null,
            crashRecover : null,
            mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
        };
        var m = mouse;
        function mouseMove(e) {
            var t = e.type;
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
            m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left;
            m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top;
            m.alt = e.altKey;
            m.shift = e.shiftKey;
            m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
            if (t === "mousedown") {
                m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which - 1];
            } else if (t === "mouseup") {
                m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
            } else if (t === "mouseout") {
                m.buttonRaw = 0;
                m.over = false;
            } else if (t === "mouseover") {
                m.over = true;
            } else if (t === "mousewheel") {
                m.w = e.wheelDelta;
            } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") {
                m.w = -e.detail;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        m.start = function (element) {
            if (m.element !== undefined) {
                m.removeMouse();
            }
            m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
            });
            m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
            m.active = true;
        }
        m.remove = function () {
            if (m.element !== undefined) {
                m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                    m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove);
                });
                m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);
                m.element = m.callbacks = undefined;
                m.active = false;
            }
        }
        return mouse;
    })();


    function update(timer) { // Main update loop
        if (ctx === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        globalTime = timer;
        display(); // call demo code
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        resizeCanvas();
        mouse.start(canvas, true);
        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }, 0);
})();
```

```html
Left click drag to create a box<br>Mouse wheel to change arc count<br>Hold right button down and wheel to change arc depth.<br>
```

Comment: thank you, I've seen this thread here too.
But I don't want to free draw it. I just wanted to display it. So basically I wanted a code of a fixed scallop shape.

Comment: Han this *"Hold right button down and wheel to change arc depth."* is impossible with a trackpad... Could you change it to *"hold straight while touching your nose with your left foot"* instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Use https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp "Bezier Curve Method" to make complicated shapes.

I suggest going on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cahqdxeshd) and messing around with the bezier curve in order to understand the complications. I hope this helped :)

Edit: Bezier curves work like this:

ctx.bezierCurveTo(Control point x, control point y, 2nd control point x, 2nd control point y, finishing x, finishing y);

Comment: woah this is quite complicated.

Comment: @DownCrow Sorry, but it is the only way. Trust me, it is super easy once you get the hang of it. :)

Comment: @DownCrow For what? Bezier/quadratic curves are made in a custom fashion so you can make any shape you want.